# How to: Instruct a screen reader what to read out in code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am unsure on how to make the screenreader read out a specific message for an email input instead of just reading 'email was selected'.

Right now when tabbing to the 'from' box, it says 'Test@gmail.com selected' when I enter Test@gmail.com into the input. I want it to say "Your email address is (read text); you may enter a different email if you would like." I am unsure of how to approach this without entering more elements on the page that say that text exactly.

```
<input role="textbox"
    tabindex="0"
    id="from-input"
    name="from-input"
    class="liberty-input col-12 disabled"
    formControlName="from"
    [readOnly]="true" />
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `aria-label` attribute?

Comment: I just tried it and it didn't output the the value in the attribute

Answer (score 0):

you can use title attribute. Just hover over input box and type something.

```js
$('#myid').keyup(function(){
 
  if($('#myid').val() !== ''){
 
 $("img").attr("width", "500");
  $('#myid').attr('title', 'your email is :'+ $('#myid').val())
 }


})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="myid" value="" title="Your mail address">Visit our HTML Tutorial</a>
```